# Angular - binding a dynamically created object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using Angular and I can't edit a dynamically created object, even though it is presented correctly (meaning the binding works).

I have the following view:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='TestApp'>
    <div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
      <input ng-model="newModel().name"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the following controller implementation:

```
    var TestApp = angular.module("TestApp", []);

    function TestCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.newModel = function(){
        return { name: 'Fresh' }    
      }
    }
```

I'm using a method to return the correct object for binding because I need to execute some logic to decide which object should be binded.
The input field displays the correct, dynamically created, value. But I cant seem to edit it.

What am I doing wrong? Is this the wrong way to achieve such a functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need it as a function? Can't you directly declare it as a scope variable?

Comment: You can't edit it because every time angular evaluates the expression, a new object is created. That does make much sense. Create the object once, and store the object in the scope.

Comment: @Chinni - I need to dynamically decide which is correct object for binding - either locate an existing object in some data structure or initialize a new one.

Comment: @JBNizet - It does make a lot of sense (and I'd be happy to accept it as the answer if you'll post it). So in your opinion - a good way to achieve this will be to use `ng-init` to dynamically decide on the object and then a simple expression in `ng-model`?

Comment: No. As documented, ng-init should almost never be used. Just put the code creating the object in the controller.

Comment: @Dani Please check my answer. What I meant was to update the `scope` variable in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning an object and by attaching a function to the scope, you can update a `scope` variable in the function.

Controller code:

```
var TestApp = angular.module("TestApp", []);

function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.newModel = {}; // initialize the scope variable
    function updateScope () {
        // do some logic
        $scope.newModel = { name: 'Fresh' }; // update it with the required object
    }

    updateScope(); // run the function
}
```

HTML code:

```
<body ng-app='TestApp'>
    <div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
        <!-- remove `()` since `newModel` is no longer a function -->
        <input ng-model="newModel.name"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this solves the issue.